Does Guile Scheme have a document generator for docstrings or documenting comments?
The source code of Guile Scheme contains docstrings (e.g., https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guile.git/tree/module/srfi/srfi-43.scm#n107). In the source code of SLib I can event see comments with some keywords like @body, @example, @var, @args (https://github.com/taktoa/slib/blob/master/bytenumb.scm#L36). It seems there should be some tools to process this stuff. But I cannot find any mentions of any documentation utilities around Guile Scheme. The only thing I found is guild doc-snarf, but it is also not documented and doesn't do anything useful with my Scheme files.
How to create module documentation from the source code of the Scheme module?

I don't think there's any standard or convention for in-source Guile documentation. The manual is written using texinfo.

I found a thread about documenting comments in a Guile mail list: https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/guile-user/2024-04/msg00051.html
Solutions mentioned there:

Guile Documentá (https://luis-felipe.gitlab.io/guile-documenta/);
guild doc-snarf;
(ice-9 documentation).

But the first doesn't work on my machine, and the last two have no documentation at all.

Answering my own question.
Yes, Guile Documentá is indeed the solution. Keywords like @var{} are indeed Texinfo tags (thank you, @shawn!). Documentá refuses to work with my code because of error in Texinfo markup. When the error was fixed (by Documentá author, thank you for your advise and for your work, Luis Felipe López Acevedo!) the Texinfo output was successfully generated from the comments in my Scheme code.
